# How do I merge the following SQL queries for performance?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two SQL queries:

1. Below query returns records in thousands(13000) and growing.

   ```
   SELECT distinct city FROM users;
   ```
2. The result of this above query becomes a parameter for next SQL query which is:

   ```
   SELECT CAST(users.lat as VARCHAR) AS latitude, 
          CAST(users.lng as VARCHAR) AS longitude,
           users.city as city,
           users.state as state 
   FROM users users 
   WHERE users .city='';
   ```

I have merged these two queries by making the first query a sub-query using `IN` clause as in:

```
SELECT CAST(users.lat as VARCHAR) AS latitude, 
       CAST(users.lng as VARCHAR) AS longitude,
       users.city as city, 
       users.state as state 
FROM users users 
WHERE users.city IN (SELECT distinct us.city FROM users us);
```

Need to know if this can be optimized further.

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  id uuid NOT NULL,
  language_id integer NOT NULL,
  lat numeric NOT NULL,
  lng numeric NOT NULL,
  state character varying,
  city character varying,
  CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First comment.  You do not need `distinct` when using `in`.  So this `where` clause suffices:

```
WHERE users.city IN (SELECT us.city FROM users us);
```

Second, it is very misleading to use a *different* table name as an alias for another table.  Instead:

```
SELECT CAST(fru.lat as VARCHAR) AS latitude, 
       CAST(fru.lng as VARCHAR) AS longitude,
       fru.city as city, 
       fru.state as state 
FROM farmrise.users fru 
WHERE fru.city IN (SELECT u.city FROM users u);
```

Most databases will generate a good query plan for this.  Personally, I would be inclined to write this as;

```
FROM farmrise.users fru 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users u WHERE u.city = fru.city);
```

This will definitely take advantage of an index on `users(city)`.

Finally, in most databases you want a length for the `VARCHAR` in the `CAST()`.  In fact, you should have a length in any database other than MySQL and derivative databases.

Comment: Postgres doesn't need a length for `varchar` either

Comment: "Second, it is very misleading to use a different table name as an alias for another table.":

there is just one table in the problem which is 'users'.